# task scheduler - run interactively as any user with admin credentials

Tags: group-policy, scheduled-task, uac

I'm trying to deploy a scheduled task with a GPO.

The task is set to run at login and executes a batch file, which then executes an EXE file.

However, I also need it to be interactive and run with admin privledges to bypass the UAC prompt for a username and password when the exe file runs.

I created the task for "Vista and later".

I've tried running the task as `mydoman\administrator` and as `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated users` with "run only when user is logged in" and "run with highest privledges" selected.

If I log in as anyone but administrator, the task does run in the background, as I can see the cmd.exe process running in task manager as mydomain\administrator. Only if I log in as administrator do I then see the cmd window with the batch script running.

How can I get the cmd window to display no matter which user logs in?